# How do I join Keys and Values. Flutter/Dart

Tags: json, flutter, dart

This is my code right now :

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> incidentList = [
                    for (final json in listNode.map((x) => x.toJson()))
                      {
                        'Code': json['field'][0]['field_value'],
                        'Description': json['field'][1]['field_value'],
                        'Organisation Unit': json['field'][2]['field_value'],
                        'Date Reported': json['field'][3]['field_value'],
                        'Status': json['field'][4]['field_value'],
                        'RunHyperlink' : json['run_hyperlink']
                      }
                  ];

                  final List<String> values =  [];
                  for(final item in incidentList){
                    values.add(item.keys.map((e)  => e.toString()).join("\n"));
                    values.add(item.values.map((e) => e.toString()).join("\n"));
                  }
                  await WriteCache.setListString(key: 'cache4', value: values);
```

How do I combine the keys and value so that my list is in the format of "key : value" instead of just value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a nested loop

```
for(final item in incidentList){
 String groupedElement = "";
   for(var innerItem in item.entries)
   {
      groupedElement += "${innerItem.key}:${innerItem.value},";
   }
   value.add(groupedElement);
}
```

Comment: Im getting this error "Error: The type 'Map<String, dynamic>' used in the 'for' loop must implement 'Iterable<dynamic>'."

Comment: brilliant it works!! but any idea on how to display it in groups in list tile, its now displaying each line separately

Comment: it still displays separately, i was thinking of something like join("\n") but im not sure where to implement it

Comment: Thank You so much, displays as intended. Do you know where I can learn more on this?

Comment: You can learn about list in flutter. https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/lists

Answer (score 0):

You can Not shure what format you want, but is sound like JSON. So if you want JSON

You can just replace:

```
await WriteCache.setListString(key: 'cache4', value: json.encode(incidentList));
```

Don't forget to import `dart:convert`:

```
import 'dart:convert';
```

And remove:

```
final List<String> values =  [];
for(final item in incidentList){
    values.add(item.keys.map((e)  => e.toString()).join("\n"));
    values.add(item.values.map((e) => e.toString()).join("\n"));
}
```

**ATTENTION**, this will return a String, not a list of String

For retrieveing a Map<String, dynamic> from your save data, just do:

```
final jsonData = json.decode(savedJsonStr);
```

Comment: im getting this error "Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<String>'."

Comment: I just update my answer to warn you about this

Comment: I have update my answer with decode json to Map<String, dynamic>